# In SQL Server 2008, will it cause slow performance of Stored Procedure if Print or Select statement to print the message unnecessarily?

Tags: sql-server-2008, select, stored-procedures, printing

In SQL Server 2008, will it cause slow performance of stored procedure if `Print` or `Select` statement to print the message unnecessarily? For eg. print 'successfully completed' or select 'successfully completed'

Answer (score 0):

A PRINT statement shouldn't affect your stored procedure performance at all.

Note, though, that the statement "prints" to the Messages window in SQL Server Management Studio--it doesn't surface to application code anyplace (such as .Net code executing that SP).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have used print statement in SP as follows: create Proc as select id, name from table1 print 'suceessfully retrieved'. will it cause slow performance whenever I execute SP.

Comment: That won't make any difference at all. The smallest time value I've ever been able to measure in SQL Server is 15 milliseconds--and that PRINT statement would take less than that. No worries.

Answer (score 0):

A handful of PRINT statements will have a negligible effect on performance - PRINT in loops that are executed many thousands of times, however, may well cause performance issues.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I have used print statement in SP as follows: create Proc as select id, name from table1 print 'suceessfully retrieved'. will it cause slow performance whenever I execute SP.

Comment: if you are printing a single statement than it would take time in milisecnds .....mean no performance issue